# How to customize the create template view of asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a view of creating template like this way-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMnjC.png

And it auto-generated a page like this-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGeeZ.png

How to increase the width of the input-text and form?

My generated register.cshtml is given below-

```
@model LoginPart.Models.Person

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Register</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>User1</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-10" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-10" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userPass, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userPass, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userPass, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}



<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom css file for your page.
In layout cshtml

```
<head>
  @RenderSection("customcss", required: false)
</head>
```

In your cshtml for page

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section customcss
{
  <link href="~/Content/YourPage.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

In YourPage.css (my example)

```
input{ width: 300px;}
form{ width: 80%; }
```

Comment out set max-width in site.css
/*input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}*/

Comment: Still it's same as before!

Comment: where did you put css file, should put in Content folder? <link href="~/Content/YourPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: I created another folder named css and there i put the mystyle.css file

Comment: Can you share your css file

Comment: whatever i put the value for the form-view or the input element it not increase more than 280px! Even if i put 500px it wont make any change! but if i put less value than 280 then the box will decrease

Comment: I wrote exactly same css as u mentioned above--- input{ width: 30px;}
form{ width: 80%; }

Comment: it only my example, you can change to your css

Comment: .form-control{width:300px}
#userName{width:300px}

Comment: but nothing has changed

Comment: Should change to width:30px !important; for overriding bootstrap

Comment: same as before! :(

Comment: You can remove input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
} in site.css